Trying to find an old black and white movie I saw in the 60's
This movie had to be from late 40's ,50's or early 60's , because I was a kid in the early 60's when I saw it.
What I remember is a rather large truck, getting stuck in a river while trying to cross it, and a man or two men getting out and using pieces of timber to try and wedge them under the rear drive wheels to get traction to the tires to unlodge the truck. They had to go under water in the swift current of the river to look and see what they were up against also. As a small boy, I remember it being quite suspensful, and I guess I liked trucks.
I don't know who any of the actors were, but I think I remember it being more like in a wooden area in the mountains rather than like a river in a western. I'm almost certain it was black and white, but I could be mistaken, I've made that mistake before. The truck I seem to remember would resemble the army trucks you see in most old war movies, twin axle, covered with tarps, that transport troups, but don't hold me to this.

Sounds like a scene from the amazing The Wages of Fear (Le salaire de la peur) from 1953, which was indeed suspenseful - their trucks were full of nitroglycerine. See if the trailer rings any bells.

Yes, it was almost certainly THE WAGES OF FEAR (1953), one of the great suspense movies of all time. It was remade as Sorcerer in 1977 with Roy Scheider, but that was a color movie. An oil company in Central America hires four men who are in desperate need of money to drive two trucks full of nitroglycerine through the mountains so that it can be used to put out an oil-field fire. There are only dirt roads, and any large bump will make the trucks explode. One of the trucks eventually does explode, and the second truck has to drive through the crater, which is filling up with crude oil. Yves Montand (right in the photo) has to somehow get his truck across the crater before it is completely impassible.
There is also a great scene where the two truck drivers have to back the trucks onto a wooden platform to make a hair-pin turn, and the platform is quite rotten and unsteady. 


Thanks Bruce for your answer,but know, this movie was not wages of fear.awhile back,another guy answered my post and said it was waiges of fear too,so I bought it and watched it,so glad I did,was an excellent movie.but it was not the one I'm searching now. This movie,the truck was definitely stuck in a moving river of water,about as deep as the rear wheels,about the same size truck as in wages of fear,maybe slightly larger, thanks everyone for the help
